# ODR and "same sequence of tokens" and "typename" vs "class" in type template parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

- [Disclaimer #1: I'm actually not referring to the C++ standard; I'm referring to `cppreference`'s ["Definitions and ODR (One Definition Rule)"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition_).]
- [Disclaimer #2: I'm actually too lazy to try it, which I defend in my mind by referring to the standard C++ disclaimer that ODR violations are not required to be diagnosed, so I probably won't learn anything by trying it.]

The C++ standard (as disclaimed in #1 above) says that one of the requirements for *not* being an ODR violation is "each definition consists of the same sequence of tokens".

Which seems pretty clear, except, I'm curious:

In declaring the type template parameters of a template, is substituting `typename` for `class` in two different definitions (in two different translation units, etc.) disallowed as well?

Because those keywords are generally interchangeable.

(I know about the special case that you can't substitute `typename` for `class` [in a template template parameter](https://bakins-bits.dev/dev/2012/11/typename-is-not-always-a-substitute-for-class-in-a-template-parameter/) in any event.)

Comment: You seem to be asking if "same tokens" means "interchangeable tokens", yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typename` and `class` are not the same token. So yes, if two definitions for the same entity differ on that, then it is an ODR violation.

The ODR rule is written with the expectation that template/inline definitions are only written out once in a header file which is then included in other files, so that such variations shouldn't happen.

Comment: What about if the template code is identical (same #include) but due to what other templates are specialized in that translation unit, the instantiated template behaves differently in different translation units? What if the result of the different instantiations is the same even if the internal logic differs?

Comment: @Ben That the sequence of tokens is identical in all definitions is only one of several conditions which need to satisfies for the ODR, see [\[basic.def.odr\]/13.8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#13.8). For example (13.9) requires that all names after lookup, overload resolution and partial template specialization matching refer to the same entity in each definition.

Comment: @Ben There are also generally rules that require that partial/explicit template specializations in multiple translation units are not "conflicting", e.g. [\[temp.expl.spec\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.expl.spec#7) requires that an explicit specialization is declared before each use in _every_ translation unit that would cause implicit instantiation. Or [\[temp.point\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.point#7.sentence-4) which requires that multiple instantiation of a template specialization when used in different TUs are identical in the ODR sense.

Comment: @Ben If the token sequence is different, but the actual behavior of the definition would be identical, it is still a ODR violation for which the standard then doesn't impose any requirement on the compiler to accept the program or have the program behave in any particular way (_ill-formed, no diagnostic required_ / _undefined behavior_) The rule could probably be written more permissively, but it handles normal use of the language.